# How can I get the list of commit and MR from 7pm before yesterday to 7pm yesterday in Bash?

Tags: bash, git, gitlab, devops

i'am using this script to get all the commit's and MR's from a specific date and time. But I'm clearly doing something wrong. I'm not sure how to get them from 7pm before yesterday to 7pm yesterday in Bash? (ie: we are on Wednesday I want the commits and MRs that occurred between 7pm on Monday and 7pm on Tuesday)

I also want to apply this script on all the submodule is it possible using git submodule foreach?

Thanks in advance for your response

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "============================================ Merges====================================================="
git log --since=before.yesterday.7:00pm --until=yesterday.7:00pm --merges --format="%s"

echo "============================================ commits  ====================================================="
git log --since=before.yesterday.7:00pm --until=yesterday.7:00pm --no-merges  --format="%s"
```

Comment: A "Merge Request" is not a git native concept, it only exists in the Gitlab UI, so `git log` can _only_ show you commits, some of which will be merge commits. That said, you haven't really explained your problem: you say you're "clearly doing something wrong", but not why you think that - what happens when you run this command, and what did you want to happen instead?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm using gitlab so that is why I talked about Merge requests and not pull requests. So I also need to find a way to display the merge requests. but my question is mainly about the since option. I want to have the list of commits and MRs from 24 hours before the day I'm using the script from 7pm to 7pm I gave an example.

Comment: OK, I get what you're trying to do, and can see you've tried some commands - but what happened when you ran those commands that makes you think you are "doing something wrong"? Was there an error message? Did the output not include the commits you were expecting? Did a cartoon character pop up saying "you're doing something wrong"?

Comment: please be nice I know I'm making something wrong because I'm not dumb. I just wrote before.yesterday in the since option because that is what I want to do but this is not the way to do it obviously.

Comment: I'm not trying to criticise you, I'm just asking you for details - **what happens when you run that code?** I don't know whether you're asking for help to solve an error message, or simply results that weren't what you were hoping for.

Comment: it does nothing when I run the code it gives a void result with only the choice of getting back to the prompt. I'm not asking for help to solve an error message I just want to know how to pass in the since options the fact that I want the list of commits from 24 hours before the day I'm using the script from 7pm to 7pm.

Answer (score 0):

There may be other problems, but the first obvious one is this:

> `--since=date`, `--after=date`
>       Show commits more recent than a specific date.
>
> `--until=date`, `--before=date`
>       Show commits older than a specific date.

Both of your dates are `yesterday.7:00pm`.  I know you show the first one as `before.yesterday.7:00pm`, but the word *before* here is just noise filler.  So you've asked for commits that are more recent than 7 PM yesterday, but no more recent than 7 PM yesterday.  At most, a commit made at *exactly* 7 PM yesterday might fit this description (depending on the boundary conditions of since and until).

You might wish to ask for "since two days ago at 7 pm, until yesterday at 7 PM", for instance.

(Note that since and until use the committer date, not the author date.)